# Which of the statements are false?

Tags: rational-numbers

I have this statement:

> Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R} - $ {$0$}, with
> $\quad acd> 0$.
>
> If $– 1 < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{b}{c} < \frac{c}{d} < \frac{d}{a} < 1,$
>
> Which of the following alternative are false?
>
> A) $\quad a < cd$
>
> B) $\quad c < ad$
>
> C) $\quad d < ac$
>
> D) $\quad ab < cd$
>
> E) $\quad ad < bc$

I'm really stuck, I've tried several things and nothing has worked for me. Some hint or guide would be useful

Comment: *real numbers other different of zero*... I'm not sure what that means. Are you saying they're all nonzero?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I already edited

Comment: What is "different *of* zero"?  Do you mean "different *from* zero"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "*different of zero*" you mean $abcd\neq 0$.

We have $a/c=(a/b)(b/c)$ so $-1<a/c<1$, and we are also given $-1<c/d<1$, $-1<d/a<1$.  Multiplying gives the contradiction $1=(acd)/(acd)<1$ hence there are no $a,b,c,d$ that satisfy the given inequality.  Hence all options are **vacuously true**.

Comment: I mean that $a,b,c,d, \in \mathbb{R} -$ {$0$}

Comment: And the answer must be $E)$

Comment: No, all of (A) - (E) are true, because there are no counterexamples.

Comment: @EduardoS. in your question, what do you mean when you use "$<$"? $<$ or $\leq$?

Comment: Some explanation of why $E$ is false is: 'Because $ad$ is positive and $bc$ negative'. And i don't know why.

Comment: @dcolazin i write the question in a correct form

Comment: So give me a witness to the fact that $bc$ is negative, because it is also vacuously true that $bc$ is positive.

Comment: I do not know. That is written in the answers. There's a development in Spanish, but I do not know how to translate it since I'm not native English, and that's why I'm looking for help here. However, here is the development in Spanish: https://i.imgur.com/vuQgd1r.png

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check where $0$ can fit ($5$ options):
$$– 1 \overbrace{<}^{<0} \frac{a}{b} \overbrace{<}^{<0} \frac{b}{c} \overbrace{<}^{<0} \frac{c}{d} \overbrace{<}^{<0} \frac{d}{a} \overbrace{<}^{<0} 1,$$
For each case, by checking signs of the numbers $a,b,c,d$, one can find only the central sign works. For example:
$$– 1 <0< \frac{a}{b} < \frac{b}{c} < \frac{c}{d} < \frac{d}{a} < 1 \Rightarrow \\
a<b<c<d<a \ ?$$
Similarly, you can reject the rest three cases by contradiction.

So we have:
$$– 1 < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{b}{c} < 0<\frac{c}{d} < \frac{d}{a} < 1 \Rightarrow \\
1) \ (a,b,c,d)=(+,-,+,+); \ \ 2) \ (a,b,c,d)=(-,+,-,-) \Rightarrow \\
1) \ E) \ ad<bc \iff (+)(+)<(-)(+) \ ? \ 2) \ E) \ ad<bc \iff (-)(-)<(+)(-) \ ?$$
I leave other options to check to you.